# For loop in python initializes an outer variable on each iteration

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary

I can't understand why the following codes gives different results:

```
from datetime import datetime

def foo():
    return {datetime.now() : True}

a = {}
a.update(foo())
a.update(foo())
a.update(foo())
```

And:

```
a = {}
for i in xrange(3):
    a.update(foo())
```

In the former `a` ends up with three elements, while in the later `a` ends up with just one element (from the last iteration).

Comment: I can't reproduce this -- Maybe my computer is slower than yours ;-)

Comment: Are you sure `datetime.now()` returns a different value in all calls in both cases?

Comment: On my machine I get three for both

Comment: Add `time.sleep(1)` in `foo` and you'll see what happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just your luck. The second code is likely to execute in a single millisecond (or microsecond, depending on your OS), and give three identical datetimes, first is less likely to do so (on your system/your way of executing code). Keep trying, you might end up with two elements. Don't write code that depends on luck.

Comment: slight correction -- only write code that depends on luck *if you intend to* :).  Luck ends up being a nice way to get random numbers :-) -- not that this would be a good way to get random numbers ...

Comment: Usually luck is a worse way to get random numbers than a carefully crafted PRG :)

Comment: I'm not actually sure that is true for some applications.  See [Hardware random number generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_random_number_generator) for example.

Comment: Hence "usually" and not "always".

Comment: I think we agree here :-).  I just wanted to point out that luck could be useful in a small handful of applications.  A vast majority however, should not rely on luck (or even implementation details IMHO)

Answer (score 3):

The number of elements you end up with will depend on how many calls to `foo` Python executes within the granularity of `datetime.now()`.

If you're running this in an interactive console then between statements executed at the prompt the console will perform housekeeping (for example, displaying the `>>>` prompt) that will significantly delay the next statement, whereas for the `for` loop the loop will be executed in its entirety before the console does anything.